# ¿Cuál es el precio medio por día de una habitación en función de si el anfitrión tiene verificado o no su perfil? en R

Tags: r

arb is:

```
daily_price
<int>
               host_identity_verified2
                      <fctr>
94                    NO VERIFICA           
125                    VERIFICA         
100                   NO VERIFICA           
120                    VERIFICA         
70                     VERIFICA         
200                   NO VERIFICA           
700                     VERIFICA            
250                     VERIFICA            
100                    NO VERIFICA          
280                      VERIFICA
```

Con la funcion:

```
arb_verifica %>% group_by(host_identity_verified2) %>% summarise(media_precio = mean(daily_price))
```

El resultado solo me da la media para

NO VERIFICA : 103.7647

VERIFICA : NA

Comment: Seguramente tienes algún valor `NA` en  `daily_price`,  agrega el parámetro `na.rm=TRUE`  en la función `mean()`

Comment: Bienvenido Victor De La Osada a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..